# MagicSuggest plugin related to calling ajax on item select and close to update database

Tags: javascript, events, magicsuggest

I am trying to implement the magicsuggest plugin into a one page app
I need the plugin to ajax server every time an item is added or removed from the selected list.

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection) {
   // save selected item to database
   addToDatabase(ms.getValue()[ms.getValue().length-1]);
})


$("span.ms-close-btn").bind("click",function(event) {
   var theValue=$(this).parent().text()
   deleteFromDatabase(tValue);
})
```

I have a one page app with these two functions. When an item is added to selection list I want to call addItemToDatabase which will submit value with ajax and add it to database

When the close button (x) is clicked, I want to let magicsuggest do its default behavior where it removes item from selection and ALSO calls my deleteFromDatabase function which will send item id/value to server via ajax and delete item from database.

I am stuck. It seems like closing always fires a selectionchange event first. But, if I isSilent or someway bypass the selectionchange then the default behavior is cancelled and the item is not removed from selected in dom.

the sample code above  will do everything correctly accept, when the close button is clicked, it will not only deleteFromDatabase, but also trigger the selectionchange and execute addToDatabase. So, the item will look like it was removed, but on refresh it is there because both add and remove functions were executed.

I hope this makes sense enough to receive some help. Am having a hard time figuring out the event behavior with the plugin.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after about 15 hours I got this working. Here are the 3 functions involved.

Again, this allows me to add to selection and delete from selection in real time with database updates.

```
    // removing item from selection

    function resetClose() {
        $("span.ms-close-btn").not($(".span.ms-close-btn.guest")).bind("click",function() {
        var tValue=$(this).parent().text()
        registration.deleteAttendingEmployee(tValue)
        resetClose() 
    })
    }

   // *** Adding item to selection

        $(ms).bind('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){
            $(ms).trigger('addToSelection',[eval(ms.getSelectedItems()),true]);
       })



    $(ms).on('addToSelection', function(selection) {
      registration.addSafetyMeetingAttendee(ms.getValue()[ms.getValue().length-1])
        ms.collapse()
        resetClose() 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is another alternative based on above**

go to magicsuggest library dev version;

find **_renderSelection:** function() {..};

find **selectedItemEl** variable;

modify the library;

original line:

```
selectedItemEl = $('<div/>', {
                            'class': 'ms-sel-item ms-sel-text ' + cfg.selectionCls + validCls,
                            html: selectedItemHtml + (index === (_selection.length - 1) ? '' : cfg.resultAsStringDelimiter)
                        }).data('json', value);
```

Updated:

```
selectedItemEl = $('<div/>', {
                    'data-id':value[cfg.valueField],
                            'class': 'ms-sel-item ms-sel-text ' + cfg.selectionCls + validCls,
                            html: selectedItemHtml + (index === (_selection.length - 1) ? '' : cfg.resultAsStringDelimiter)
                        }).data('json', value);
```

Capture the selection event change and bind close button

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function (e, m) {
          $(".ms-close-btn").bind("click", function (event) {
              var theValue = $(this).parent().attr("data-id");
              alert(theValue);             
          });
      });
```